# callouts above the pins

Tags: iphone, view, callouts

I'm making an app, using mapkit & making the callout's on my own, but I have a problem there.
I put a custom pin's image too, & the callout's bubble, appears behind the pins, & want to show them above them. 
I tried 
[calloutMapAnnotationView.superview bringSubviewToFront:calloutMapAnnotationView] in view For Annotation function.
But is not working...
Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: How are you making the custom callouts?

Comment: With a subclass of MKAnnotationView

Comment: Try the APPLE's sample code for map callouts. Its just the thing you are searching for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try going through this [detailed tutorial](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) on what you're trying to do.  It's hard to be able to give more detailed information without knowing exactly what's going on in the code.

Comment: I used that tutorial to make the app. but the problem is, that with several MKAnnotation, the callout appears behind the pois... & I don't know how could I avoid it. Thank you anyway :)